# Tab hover event in chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does chrome extensions api provide an event for hovering with your mouse on tabs ? I'm unable to find it in the docs, or maybe there is an undocumented way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is no way of doing this currently. I hope they add it !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#events) for Chrome extension development, there doesn't seem to be an onHover() event for tabs at the moment. This needs to come out!

Comment: It's 2014 already and there seems to be no plan on making this happening.